# In Teams: After selecting the value from input.choice or input.date the selected value disappears after submitting it

Tags: microsoft-teams

When user select the value from input.choice and then submit the action, after submitting it,  selected value gets disappear.

This issue appeared recently first it was Showing the selected value.

I am expecting the selected value should be shown in input.choice and input.date field after submitting it.

Comment: It's the by design behavior but after submitting the card, you can again bind the values and refresh the existing card.
There is a method called UpdateActivityAsnyc() which is available in TurnContext.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **by design behavior**.
but after submitting the card, you can again bind the values and refresh the existing card.

There is a method called UpdateActivityAsnyc() which is available in TurnContext.